# Type 'Promise' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' in typescript problem

Tags: typescript

I have two positions from which I expect a promise
To shorten the code, I said to make a function like this

```
const [comments, posts]: Promise<object | null> = await Promise.all(
    [
        CommentsService.getCommentsByInterval(isoInterval, clientId),
        PostsService.getPostsByInterval(isoInterval, domain)
    ]
);
```

As for functionality, everything is ok, but I have an error from the editor that I can't figure out how to solve

```
TS2322: Type '[object | null, object | null]' is not assignable to type 'Promise '.
TS2488: Type 'Promise<object | null>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.  reports.controller.ts(30, 15): Did you forget to use 'await'?
```

```
In each function I have a return await prisma.model... etc
```

I tried to activate dom.iterator in tsconfig but it doesn't help me, this is what I saw recommended in other articles but I didn't solve it
Do you have any idea why this error occurs?

I tried to give different types to the function but in vain

Answer (score 1):

`await Promise.all` doesn't return a promise. You have already waited for it to resolve. `Promise.all` returns a promise that resolves to an array, so your type should actually be:

```
const [comments, posts]: (object | null)[] = await Promise.all(
```

Also, I think you shouldn't annotate this either way... TypeScript should be able to infer the types for you:

```
const [comments, posts] = await Promise.all(
```